# Call footerCallback by variable DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I create a Datatable and I add rows by method "row.add"

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
...
...
...
table.row.add(...)
...
...
...
```

I want sum some columns by method "footerCallback"

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        }
});
```

But he throws a mistake like that [error](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3) because it is already initialized

How can I solve the problem, keeping both method "add" and "footerCallback?

Comment: You can destroy it and init again. Or you can move `footerCallback` to the first block.

Comment: I can't destroy table. I try to move.

Answer (score 0):

You can only create the table once - so all the callbacks, settings, options, etc. are all defined on that first initialisation. After that, you can get the handle again by `$('#example').DataTable()`, but you can't declare settings or add new ones after that first creation.

For you, your first code block creates the table, then in the second code block you're defining a callback, so this isn't allowed. The fix is simply to declare that callback when you first initialise the table.